# Qual è il significato di "strafare" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Non so niente di te*, di Paola Mastrocola, ho letto:

> E finalmente entrava in sala portando trionfale il vassoio del dolce. Lo depose in centro tavola. La ciambella bavarese rosa e bianca, gigante, ora troneggiava un po' tremula, come di dovere. Accanto, un bricco di cioccolato fuso ancora caldo da versare sopra, e una ciotolina di nocciole sminuzzate, per chi volesse *strafare*.

Nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/strafare/) ho trovato che "strafare" significa "fare più del necessario o del conveniente". Comunque, non riesco a capire il suo significato nel brano precedente. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Comment: Significa “esagerare”.

Comment: Infatti, “esagerare”: cioè, chi non si accontenta del dolce o quel che era, può renderlo ancor più ricco con il cioccolato e le nocciole.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ciò che hai trovato nel vocabolario Treccani è, ovviamente, corretto.

Nella frase da te postata, *strafare* indica il fatto che si voglia mangiare il dolce arricchendolo ancora di più (la bavarese di suo è una torta già bella pesante e calorica). Infatti ci si riferisce ad *un bricco di cioccolato fuso ed una ciotola di nocciole sminuzzate* oltre a quello che già c'era da mangiare.

Comment: A orecchio, più che “più del dovuto”, in questo contesto direi che si riferisca a rendere ancor più ricco e goloso un dolce presumibilmente già completo. @Charo, accanto a cosa stavano il bricco e la ciotolina?

Comment: @DaG: Stavano accanto a un dolce, credo di ricordare che fosse una bavarese (adesso non ho il libro con me perché non sono a casa).

Comment: @DaG: Ok, se stavano accanto ad un dolce già completo di suo, hai ragione. Se puoi, Charo, aggiungi alla tua frase il riferimento al dolce così posso integrare la risposta

Comment: Lo farò questa sera quando sarò arrivata a casa.

Comment: @Charo: Certo fai con calma, era solo un consiglio ;) Buona giornata

Comment: Ho riportato un brano più ampio. @DaG: In effetti, quello che stava accanto era una bavarese.

Comment: @Charo ¿C'è in Spagna una letteratura simile a quella italiana di questo genere?

Comment: Non so cosa vuoi dire, @Elberich.

Comment: Ho aggiornato la mia risposta